# Is there any way to setup an python file to run an exe?

Tags: python

Is there any way to setup an python file to run an exe without knowing the exact location but they are in the same folder?
I want to send an prank file to an friend and i would want to make an python file to run an .exe file without him knowing (that .exe file is in the same folder location)
I want to add the command to this script:

```
import random
from tkinter import *
from random import randint
import time
import threading

root = Tk()
root.attributes("-alpha", 0)
root.overrideredirect(1)
root.attributes("-topmost", 1)

def placewindows():
    while True:
        win = Toplevel(root)
        win.geometry("300x60+" + str(randint(0, root.winfo_screenwidth() - 300)) + "+" + str(randint(0, root.winfo_screenheight() - 60)))
        win.overrideredirect(1)
        Label(win, text="You got hacked", fg="red").place(relx=.38, rely=.3)
        win.lift()
        win.attributes("-topmost", True)
        win.attributes("-topmost", False)
        root.lift()
        root.attributes("-topmost", True)
        root.attributes("-topmost", False)
        time.sleep(.05)

threading.Thread(target=placewindows).start()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without knowing the exact location but they are in the same folder?". If you know they are in the same folder then you know the location.

Comment: You can (usually) determine what folder the running Python script is in by extracting it from the built-in `__file__` variable.

Answer (score 1):

To figure out where your script is running from, check the `__file__` special variable. You can then strip off the filename and add on the name of whatever else you're trying to run:

```
import pathlib  # Modern path-handling is nice

me = pathlib.Path(__file__)
mydir = me.parent
mysibling = mydir / 'nameofexecutable.exe'

subprocess.run([mysibling])
```

The three lines in the middle can be one-lined to just:

```
mysibling = pathlib.Path(__file__).with_name('nameofexecutable.exe')
```

if you like (I gave the three lines to show how you can do it component by component with relative ease, but `with_name` is really the better solution for this specific case since it directly replaces the script name with the sibling file name).

---

As a side-note, your original code here is terrible. GUI programs should perform *all* GUI work in a single thread, on the event loop; in this case, you're intentionally doing all the manipulation of the GUI from a different thread, while the main thread's event loop is doing nothing but the drawing updates those changes require. There's no reason to do this, and it's dangerous to do so (`tkinter` may do okay by marshalling the commands between threads, and do okay because Python's GIL prevents data structure corruption, but it's slower; many GUI toolkits will just die if you start drawing from multiple threads). The *much* better version of your code would be:

```
# All code above this point unchanged, aside from removing import threading

def placewindows():
    # Remove loop; the after call at the end gets the same effect

    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.geometry("300x60+" + str(randint(0, root.winfo_screenwidth() - 300)) + "+" + str(randint(0, root.winfo_screenheight() - 60)))
    win.overrideredirect(1)
    Label(win, text="You got hacked", fg="red").place(relx=.38, rely=.3)
    win.lift()
    win.attributes("-topmost", True)
    win.attributes("-topmost", False)
    root.lift()
    root.attributes("-topmost", True)
    root.attributes("-topmost", False)

    # Schedule the next call 50 ms from now
    # Unlike time.sleep(0.05), this doesn't block
    # the event loop, so the GUI remains responsive
    root.after(50, placewindows)

# No need for a thread, just call directly
placewindows()  # Performs the first GUI update and schedules the next
                # The mainloop will finish up any drawing this call requires
                # as soon as it launches
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -2):

if I understand what you need, the file .exe that you want to run are in the same folder that your file .py.
You can use os.listdir() to find the file:

```
import os
for i in os.listdit():
    print(i)
```

If you know the file name, the code up is unecessary.
To run a file,  you just had to validate the file name (i) or if the file is the only .exe at folder, you can use i.find('.exe).

After you find the file name (i):

```
import os
import subprocess

path = os.getcwd()
filepath = (path+i)
p = subprocess.Popen(filepath, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = p.communicate()
```

Comment: The OP almost certainly knows the name of the executable (they either put it there, or happen to know it's located there already), so there's no real need for `listdir`. On top of that, this code is: 1) Looking in the *working* directory, which is not necessarily the same as the *script* directory (if I'm `cd`-ed to `/foo`, and I run `/bar/script.py`, the working directory remains `/foo`, but the OP's executable is in `/bar` so this won't find it), 2) Failing to properly join the paths (no path separator between `path` and `i`), and 3) Needlessly using `shell=True` (a generally terrible idea).